# Raspberry picamera on ubuntu not found

Tags: raspberrypi

Hi i am trying to install picamera for raspberry pi on ubuntu ..

for that i used this link [here](http://www.knight-of-pi.org/installing-the-camera-module-for-ubuntu/)

but whenever i try to run this command

```
sudo apt-get install libraspberrypi-dev
```

it gives me error unable to find package :(

would anyone here to help me out ?
i also wanna install raspistill on this os and maybe raspi-config :( :(

> uname -a
>
> Linux ubuntu 5.3.0-1018-raspi2 #20-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 3 19:45:46 UTC
>   2020 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux –

downloaded from [here](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi)

> ubuntu-19.10.1-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img
>   [This one](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi/thank-you?version=19.10.1&architecture=arm64%20raspi3)

raspberry pi 3b+

Comment: You haven't said what release you are using, but the page you linked to was from 2015 so will refer to a really old & EOL release of Ubuntu (it doesn't say). The package name may have changed, or instructions are *out-of-date* for any modern release of Ubuntu, but your release details are the first step.

Comment: Linux ubuntu 5.3.0-1018-raspi2 #20-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 3 19:45:46 UTC 2020 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

Comment: i am sorry , i edited :)

Comment: i am so sorry for my mistakes :( i am really new , anyways i provided more details now thanks for answering

Answer (score 2):

It seems nowadays that only the magic line `start_x=1` will do the trick.

You need to add the line to `/boot/firmware/config.txt`.

1. Open `config.txt` for editing:

   ```bsh
   sudo nano /boot/firmware/config.txt
   ```
2. Add the following line:

   ```
   start_x=1
   ```

   Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit.
3. Reboot your system.
4. Update your system to install the necessary drivers:

   ```bsh
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt upgrade
   ```

Comment: Did not work for me on `Ubuntu 20.04/arm64`. There are various sections in `/boot/firmware/config.txt`, and I added the `start_x=1` at the end of that file (and not in the `pi4` section), and also in the `/boot/firmware/usrcfg.txt` without any luck.

Comment: You need to have Ubuntu 20.04/aarch64. In other words an RPi 4 with an Ubuntu 20.04 OS

Comment: the file I used for installation is named `ubuntu-20.04-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi.img.xy`. Is there any other for installing 20.04 on arm64? I installed it on a RPI4.

Comment: I've used the new Raspberry Pi Image Tool from this site [https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/) and selected the Ubuntu 20.04 option as OS. This gives you the aarch64 installation. Please note, you don't have Raspistill or Raspivideo. Instead use a tool like vokoscreen to get connection to your Raspicam

Comment: Confirmed, worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 (32bit, armhf).

Comment: Still getting `Unable to lcoate package libraspberrypi-dev`, on Ubuntu 20.04.1 on Pi 2 Model B armv71 32-bit. I modified usercfg.txt instead of config.txt.

Comment: I think Pi 2 is simply a bit too old. I never tried it.